# legend color doesn't match map colors python

Tags: python, legend, choropleth, pysal

I'm using the vba_choropleth to create Value-by-Alpha Choropleth, but the legend doesn't match the color of my map.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
vba_choropleth(x, y, gdf,
               alpha_mapclassify=dict(classifier='quantiles', k=5),
               rgb_mapclassify=dict(classifier='quantiles', k=5),
               legend=True, ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: I have not used this library, but when I run [this sample](https://github.com/pysal/splot/blob/master/notebooks/mapping_vba.ipynb) in Colab, it shows the legend as shown in the sample. The only difference is the gdf file. Is there any difference there?